# Conditional and combined with or statements

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file which looks like this:

```
ID   Status  SP1   SP2
5       I     D     R
5       C     D     D
5       C     R     D
5       I     S     D
5       D     R     S
6       C     R     R
6       I     D     D
6       I     S     D
6       D     D     D
7       I     R     D
7       C     D     D
7       D     D     D
```

I want to write a code which says, If Status==D and SP1 or SP2==R then create a new column called Level and fill all rows within applicable ID with D1. If there is no R for SP1 or SP2 with a status of D, but If Status==C and SP1 or SP2==R then create a new column and fill all rows with applicable ID with D2. If there is no R for SP1 or SP2, but Status==I and SP1 or SP2==R then create a new column and fill all rows with applicable ID with D3.  Else return D4

My desired output is:

```
ID   Status  SP1   SP2  Level
5       I     D     R    D1
5       C     D     D    D1
5       C     R     D    D1
5       I     S     D    D1
5       D     R     S    D1
6       C     R     R    D2
6       I     D     D    D2
6       I     S     D    D2
6       D     D     D    D2
7       I     R     D    D3
7       C     D     D    D3
7       D     D     D    D3
```

I am currently trying a code like this:

```
df['Level']=np.nan

    def f(x):
      if x['STATUS'] == 'D' and x['SP1'] == 'R' or x['SP2']=='R': return 'D1'
      elif x['STATUS'] == 'C' and x['SP1'] == 'R' or x['SP2']=='R': return 'D2'
      elif x['STATUS'] == 'I' and x['SP1'] == 'R' or x['SP2']=='R': return 'D3'
      else: return 'D4'

    df['Level'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)    

    print df
```

but this returns this:

```
    ID STATUS SP1 SP2 Level
0    5      I   D   R    D1
1    5      C   D   D    D4
2    5      C   R   D    D2
3    5      I   S   D    D4
4    5      D   R   S    D1
5    6      C   R   R    D1
6    6      I   D   D    D4
7    6      I   S   D    D4
8    6      D   D   D    D4
9    7      I   R   D    D3
10   7      I   S   D    D4
11   7      D   D   D    D4
```

First off, why does index row 0 return a `D1` when there is an `R` for `SP2`?  And index row 5 returns `D1` when I would expect a `D2`.

Comment: What operator precedence are you expecting here? Perhaps you could add some parentheses to make it clearer.

Comment: For the code I provided, I would expect if there is an `R` in `SP1` or `SP2` and `Status`==`D` to return a D1. If there is an `R` in `SP1` or `SP2` and `Status`==`C` to return a D2. If there is an `R` in `SP1` or `SP2` and `Status`==`I` to return a D3. If none of those conditions are met to return `D4`.  That is not my desired output, but I think I can make it work if I could even get the output to that point.

Comment: I suggest you read https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you have an R in SP2, will result in D1.  This is because `and` has higher precedence than `or`.  So your first if statement:

```
if x['STATUS'] == 'D' and x['SP1'] == 'R' or x['SP2']=='R':
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (x['STATUS'] == 'D' and x['SP1'] == 'R') or x['SP2']=='R':
```

So any row where `x['SP2']=='R'` will match that first condition.

I think what you want, instead, is:

```
if x['STATUS'] == 'D' and (x['SP1'] == 'R' or x['SP2']=='R'):
```